# Error: src/main/aerospike.c:17:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory; unable to install aeropike with python3

Tags: python-3.6, aerospike, client-library

Kindly refer to this issue for details:

https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-python/issues/220

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question needs to contain all the details, not just external links + fluff.

Comment: This isn’t a question  about programming. You have an issue open  in the repo, why would you put that link here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should install python3.6 development package, for an example for ubuntu/debian:

sudo apt install python3.6-dev

Answer (score 0):

To install the correct version of python do: `sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev`
then: `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`
To install pip3: `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`
Then do `sudo -H pip3 install aerospike` to install aerospike

Now you should be able to run aerospike with python3!